# What is "immediate regret" and how is it computed?

Tags: model-evaluation, metric

In Figure 1 of [Springenberg et al.'s (2016) paper, "Bayesian optimization with robust Bayesian neural networks,"](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/6117-bayesian-optimization-with-robust-bayesian-neural-networks.pdf) I saw method evaluation metric called "immediate regret".

However, I am not familiar with it and I failed to find any literature which would clearly explain it. Could someone explain what kind of evaluation metric is it and how to compute it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find [Shah & Ghahramani's (2015) paper in *Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems* called "Parallel predictive entropy search for batch global optimization of expensive objective functions,"](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5804-parallel-predictive-entropy-search-for-batch-global-optimization-of-expensive-objective-functions.pdf) where they say (p. 6):

> We measure performance after $t$ batch evaluations using *immediate
>   regret*, $r_t = |f(\tilde{x_t}) - f(x^*)|$, where $x^*$ is the known
>   optimizer of $f$ and $\tilde{x_t}$ is the recommendation of an
>   algorithm after $t$ batch evaluations